# Rails how to create a many to many relationship and also save who created it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 Models

- User
- Company
- Tag

I would like to create a many to many relationship between `User` and `Tags` but I also want to know which `Company` created this relationship so that when the users are searched in the database by tags the system only searches with in the tags assigned by the company.

I know how to create a has_many relationship

```
User
has_many: tags, through: :user_tags
has_many: user_tags

Tag
has_many: users, through: :user_tags
has_many: user_tags

UserTag
belongs_to: user
belongs_to: tag
```

But what I dont understand is how to store who created this relationship and then later pull all the uses tagged by a specific company.

I will really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add company_id field to UserTag Model to represent which company created this entry.
Then for your query 'when the users are searched in the database by tags the system only searches with in the tags assigned by the company'

> required_tag_id = assign_required_tag_id
>
> required_company_id = assign_required_company_id
>
> user_ids = UserTag.where(tag_id: required_tag_id).where(company_id: required_company_id).pluck(:user_id)
>
> users = User.where(id: user_ids)

Comment: Thanks to have a look, I am trying some sense out of this :) this does look like something that will work

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps you out

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many: tags, through: :user_tags
has_many: user_tags

Class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: users, through: :user_tags
  has_many: user_tags
end

Class UserTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: user
  belongs_to: tag
  belongs_to :company
  before_save :set_company

  private
    def set_company
      self.company = "your logic for associating the company"
    end
end

#migration for user_tags

create_table :user_tags do |t|
  t.references :user
  t.references :company
  t.references :tag
end

for fetching users tagged with a specific tag by a specific company

UserTag.where(company_id: 'the company id', tag_id: 'the tag id').users
```

Comment: @Saadia Cool. Please let me know if you still face any difficulty.